# Optimized query to get the most recent records for each person in a log table

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

Is there a better way to setup this query?

```
select * 
from peopleLog
where index in (select max(index) index from peopleLog group by personID)
```

I have a log table that is inserted into every time a person's record is updated. The records are added, not replaced. This means that the table contains multiple records for each person. I want to pull the most resent record for each person from this table. The table has about 30 fields, so I don't think that grouping would be the best option, but I might be wrong.

- The index field is the identity field in this SQL Server table, and is set to auto increment.
- personID is the person's identification number and is unique the person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use window function instead:

```
select * from (
   select * , row_number() over (partition by personID order by index desc) rn
   from peopleLog
) t where t.rn = 1
```

also an index on personId and "index" column would help)

Answer (score 0):

Often a correlated subquery has the best performance:

```
select pl.* 
from peopleLog pl
where pl.index = (select max(pl2.index)
                  from peopleLog pl2
                  where pl2.personID = pl.personID
                 );
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `peopleLog(personID, index)`.